# where we use JAAS

Tags: java, security, jaas

I am learning Java Security JCE/JAAS. I am not able to get a example where we need to implement JAAS login module in real word webapplication.

Can any one please guide me where I can implement JAAS in my web application. as much i know this is authentication and authorization service.

///
If my understanding is correct now, it means if there is any service(Like LDAP) is running in our webserver or any other webserver, and if  we want to consume that service then we need to implement JAAS to authenticate our application.

Comment: I agree, I know how to implement, but will you please explain any scenario where  i can implement this.

Comment: I would like to make an addendum, if possible. I believe that [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43220700/3542189) may help in understanding your question. Conceptually saying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JAAS is one way of implementing login on a container. JAAS main benefits come from the facts that it is a standard framework integrated in the JRE - so you get plenty of information, samples, connectors, etc - and that it properly separates the various concerns of user authentication.

In particular, it clearly separates authentication (validating the supplied credentials) and authorization (role and permissions granted to the user).

While authentication is very often "generic" or "external", for instance using an LDAP server, authorization is often tightly coupled with you application: roles and permissions are usually specific to the business problem the application addresses.

Implementing your own JAAS module is a simple way of addressing this issue, while staying within the boundaries of a well-defined framework and without having to provide a low level implementation to inject the module with the login cycle and session management of the container.

Comment: I would like to make an addendum, if possible. I believe that [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43220700/3542189) may help in understanding your answer. Conceptually saying.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to implement your own JAAS login module with standard servlet containers unless you want to modify its standard behaviour as they provide you with several standard means to achieve it.

Here you will find a tutorial showing how to use the form login with Tomcat (no need for rolling you own LoginModule):
http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-use-form-authentication-with-tomcat.html

Comment: as usual, for this kind of questions google gives better "answers": http://blog.frankel.ch/custom-loginmodule-in-tomcat; just remember to add the name of realm in the <login-config> of your web.xml

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you, as the application developer, do not implement JAAS modules.  instead, you choose which JAAS module you need to use for your application from pre-existing modules included in the app server you are using.  most application servers come with a variety of implementations which allow you to do common things like authenticate using info from a database, ldap, active directory, kerberos, etc.  you would determine which authentication source you need to use and configure your application appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

The main advantage of JAAS is that its pam that is pluggable authentication module.. thus if an application wants to be separated from the authentication and authorization system you can use JAAS. moreover JAAS unlike java general security not only verifies the code source but also the person using the code source to access.. so thus if a web app needs pam and the authorization should be of code source as well as code handler then JAAS is better.