# What is the difference between JAAS and JAAP?

Tags: java, security

What is the difference between JAAS and JAAP ?

`JAAS`: Java Authentication and Authorization Service

`JAAP`: ??

Comment: JAAP? where did you find that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know it's an old question, but just to collaborate, we have the definition:

> Security services: Java Authentication and Authorization Service (**JAAS**) enables services to authenticate and enforce access controls upon users. The Java Authorization Service Provider Contract for Containers (**JACC**) defines a contract between a Java EE application server and an authorization service provider, allowing custom authorization service providers to be plugged into any Java EE product. Java Authentication Service Provider Interface for Containers (**JASPIC**) defines a standard interface by which authentication modules may be integrated with containers so that these modules may establish the authentication identities used by containers. <sub>[[Antonio Goncalves, 2013](http://www.allitebooks.com/beginning-java-ee-7) - pag 4]</sub>

With letter soup above, we can confuse the acronym Java Authorization **Service Provider Contract for Containers - JACC** and confuse the usage and the community associates "service providers to be plugged" and use as JAAP. I believe this may have happened.

---

**Reference**:
<sub>[Antonio Goncalves, 2013]. Available in **[Beginning Java EE 7](http://www.allitebooks.com/beginning-java-ee-7)**. Access: 4 Apr, 2017.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

I do not remember exactly, but ignore JAAP is an old name of JAAS

Java Authentication and Authorization ... Pluggable Module