# What is the difference between JAAS, SAML and Realm

Tags: java, security, saml, jaas, jdbcrealm

I was trying to learn `JAAS`, then i came up with the terms `SAML` and `Realm`, and now I am confused.

In any of the basic tutorials of `JAAS`, we are pretty much configuring the basic that a normal `Realm` configuration is. If I read configuration of `SAML` then it looks similar as `JAAS`. I have absolutely no idea why different names. May be **SAML** is built on **Realm** and **JAAS** on **SAML**, not sure can any body please clearly state the difference.

Please a humble request if you share any link, Please define a bit of it, so that it help me when i am reading them.

I have successfully configured, JAAS's BASIC and FROM based authentication on both JBOSS and Glassfish. It helped me to protect my `JSP` and `Servelets` (Web Project). where to look if I want to protect an **EJB** as part of my application.

Comment: I would like to make an addendum, if possible. I believe that [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43220700/3542189) may help in understanding your question. Conceptually saying.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

JAAS is a set of standard APIs for Java SE and EE which provide basic ways to achieve authentication and limited authorization. The typical use of JAAS for authentication is through LoginModules. Implementation of a LoginModule interface (javax.security.auth.spi.LoginModule) is able to authenticate user based on credentials provided by the caller in CallbackHandler. Most application servers allows you to plug-in your own LoginModules. Other key concepts of JAAS are Subject (a collection of information about a user) and Principal (a single attribute of a user - an ID, a password). Capabilities of JAAS for authorization are rather limited and are rarely used directly.

The standard authentication mechanism for Java web applications (like FORM, BASIC or DIGEST declared in your web.xml descriptor) typically delegate verification of the provided credentials to the configured JAAS LoginModules.

Realm is a concept used to denote separation of authentication and authorization policies for different applications/systems. E.g. if you want to authenticate users in application A using LDAP and applicaton B uses database table, you can put them into different security realms, so that their security requirments are isolated and correctly enforced. The typical system which uses this term is Tomcat, but you will find similarities in othe containers/application servers too. In most cases (e.g. when depoying a single application) you don't need to worry about Realms too much.

Java EE provides standard mechanisms for securing of EJBs using role based access control (RBAC). You first define which roles are applicable to your application, then define which users accessing your application belong to which roles. You can then use either declarative authorization (= annotate your methods with security annotations such as @RolesAllowed, @PermitAll, @DeclareRoles, or do the same using XML descriptors) or programmatic authorization (= test whether user belongs to a role by calling isCallerInRole on EJBContext directly in your code). A basic tutorial can be found here http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbyl.html

SAML is a very different beast from the previous ones. In a very simplistic way you can see SAML WebSSO as an authentication method. Generally SAML is a standard which defines an XML-based protocol used to transfer information about users, their authentication events and security attributes between remote systems in a secure way. Apart from the protocol itself SAML standard defines typical use-cases for the protocol, the most common being Web Single Sign-On (a possibility to authenticate user externally from the application at an entity called Identity Provider and login to an application - Service Provider without revealing user's credentials to it). In these use-cases SAML is similar to OpenID or OAuth 2.0 authentication you can see provided by Facebook or Google to 3rd party developers.

Hope this helps,
Vladimir Schafer

Comment: @VladimirSachafer , I would like to make an addendum, if possible. I believe that [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43220700/3542189) may help in understanding your answer. Conceptually saying.

Answer (score 2):

See if this helps you. A realm is a area where a specific configuration is in place. JAAS and SAML are both authentication modules that can be configured to handle authentication on that reaml. SAML is an authentication scheme. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_Assertion_Markup_Language

Answer (score 2):

To add to the other answers, I found the following explanation from [this article](http://www.drdobbs.com/web-development/saml-jaas-role-based-access-control-par/208402532) to be helpful:

> In reality, SAML and JAAS are two distinct security frameworks. SAML is an XML framework for exchanging authentication and authorization information. SAML provides a standard XML schema for specifying authentication, attribute, and authorization decision statements, and it additionally specifies a Web services-based request/reply protocol for exchanging these statements.
>
> JAAS, on the other hand, through implementation-specific login modules receives information about the user, authenticates the user, and verifies that they are a valid subject.

So as I understand it, JAAS can be used to implement custom authentication and authorization for your app, and there are many possible ways to do this, some of which involve SAML. For example, you could use SAML to get the user's identity and role/group information; this would be stored in XML tokens that your JAAS module would need to parse.

Comment: I would like to make an addendum, if possible. I believe that [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43220700/3542189) may help in understanding your answer. Conceptually saying.