# JAAS and Spring Integration

Tags: spring, jaas, integrate

I have a Dynamic Web Project with JAAS, it has a LoginModule.

Now, I have a ROLE and I give to it a  privileges like this:

```
 <security-constraint>
<display-name>PRIVILEGES</display-name>
<web-resource-collection>
  <web-resource-name>PRIVATE</web-resource-name>
  <url-pattern>/usuario/*</url-pattern>
  <url-pattern>/Data</url-pattern> <-- This is a Servlet. (JAAS Protect it)
  <url-pattern>/getEstudent</url-pattern> <-- RequestMapping from Spring.(JAAS does not protect it)
  <http-method>POST</http-method>
  <http-method>GET</http-method>
</web-resource-collection>
<auth-constraint>
  <role-name>USER1</role-name>
</auth-constraint>
```

I have integrated this with Spring. And I want to protect this url "getEstudiante". But the JAAS does not protect it.

How to do to protect a "requestmapping" from a Controller?, Thanks.

Comment: How do you acess the URL /getEstudent? Can you post the entire URL?

Comment: I've update the question @TiagoMussi

Comment: So.. you access your page like this 'localhost/getEstudent'? @JoanSanchez

Comment: I have a Dynamic web project. The project name is "project" then the url is 'localhost/project/getEstudent' @TiagoMussi

Comment: Can you post your entire web.xml?

Comment: @JoanSanchez , I would like to make an addendum, if possible. I believe that [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43220700/3542189) may help in understanding your answer. Conceptually saying.

Comment: @pss1suporte I have resolved my problem. I only was write correctly url.